# why alluxio files keep a state of TO_BE_PERSISTED all the time

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, alluxio

I have deployed an `Alluxio` cluster based on `HDFS` cluster. When I use Alluxio Native Java Api to write some files to Alluxio with setting writetype ASYNC_THROUGH, the files (even just having 1G) seem not be written to HDFS, keep a state of TO_BE_PERSISTED all the time after few days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer. I find the log "ERROR DefaultAsyncPersistHandler - Not all the blocks of file /test/sample_data/order_detail_titile_2.0.txt stored on the same worker", When using ASYNC_THROUGH, Alluxio request all file blockers in one worker. There is no problem where I use CACHE_THROUGH